# How to call Shopify metafields for a variant in .js?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

Is there any way to call metafields image positions in variants? It works fine in liquid obviously, but I have one function which needs the data as well, but can only be loaded from javascript. I don't have a problem getting variant.id or featured_image, however metafields I just don't know what to do.
The liquid code (simplified) which fetches image positions is:

```
                      {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
                    <option data-image-positions="{{variant.metafields.variant.image_position}}">
                    </option>
                  {%- endfor -%}
```

Would appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

JS always renders AFTER Liquid. So use Liquid to render values into your JS, and then you can freely use JS to do as you wish. Has always been a thing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, you can add below script in to markup

```html
<script>
// variable holding id and size details
const imagePositions = [];

// loop
{%- for variant in product.variants -%}

  // pushing data what we need
  imagePositions.push({
    id: {{variant.id}},
    image_position: {{variant.metafields.variant.image_position}}
    // if position is in string use quotes '{{variant...}}'
  });
{%- endfor -%}

// you can use imagePositions array to anywhere in js 
console.log(imagePositions);
</script>
```

### Your output will be

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    image_position: 100 // your position
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image_position: 200 // your position
  }
]
```

if any doubt please comment.